Display Profit Label for Each Buy and Sell Order
I'm writing an indicator to identify potential trade points and the best profit resulting from each order. However, it seems that the profit levels were not calculated as I expected and were only displayed in the last 2 orders, not in all orders, and also not the maximum profit level of each order. buy and sell orders.
I look forward to receiving everyone's help regarding this case. I am truly grateful for all the help.
Here is my result image, profit labels were only displayed in the last 2 orders, and it's not correct for SELL order.

This is my code.
//@version=5
indicator("My SMA Crossover Strategy", shorttitle="SMA Crossover", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/7

sma20 = ta.sma(close, 20)

buyCondition = ta.crossover(close, sma20)

sellCondition = ta.crossunder(close, sma20)

plot(sma20, color=color.red)

var float buyPrice = na
var float sellPrice = na
if (buyCondition)
    buyPrice := close
else if (sellCondition)
    buyPrice := na

if (sellCondition)
    sellPrice := close
else if (buyCondition)
    sellPrice := na

highestProfitPct = na(buyPrice) ? na : (high - buyPrice) / buyPrice * 100
lowestProfitPct = na(sellPrice) ? na : (-low + sellPrice) / sellPrice * 100

if (buyCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="Buy", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.green, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

if (sellCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="Sell", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.red, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

var label labelhigh = na
var label labellow = na

if (not na(highestProfitPct)) 
    label.delete(labelhigh)
    labelhigh := label.new(bar_index, high, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(highestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.blue, yloc=yloc.price)
    //label.new(bar_index, high, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(highestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.blue, yloc=yloc.price)

if (not na(lowestProfitPct))
    label.delete(labellow)
    labellow := label.new(bar_index, low, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(lowestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.orange, yloc=yloc.price)
    //label.new(bar_index, low, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(lowestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.orange, yloc=yloc.price)
 


I try this code and still get problems. I need the profit labels to display correctly for all trades on the chart. The BUY order's profit label is at the highest price position and is updated each time a higher profit level is established. The same goes for the profit label of the SELL order.
Many thanks for any help!

//@version=5
indicator("My SMA Crossover Strategy", shorttitle="SMA Crossover", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/7


sma20 = ta.sma(close, 20)

buyCondition = ta.crossover(close, sma20)

sellCondition = ta.crossunder(close, sma20)


plot(sma20, color=color.red)

var float buyPrice = na
var float sellPrice = na
if (buyCondition)
    buyPrice := close
else if (sellCondition)
    buyPrice := na

if (sellCondition)
    sellPrice := close
else if (buyCondition)
    sellPrice := na

highestProfitPct = na(buyPrice) ? na : (high - buyPrice) / buyPrice * 100
lowestProfitPct = na(sellPrice) ? na : (-low + sellPrice) / sellPrice * 100

if (buyCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="Buy", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.green, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

if (sellCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="Sell", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.red, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

var label labelhigh = na
var label labellow = na

if (not na(highestProfitPct)) 
    label.delete(labelhigh)
    labelhigh := label.new(bar_index, high, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(highestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.blue, yloc=yloc.price)
    //label.new(bar_index, high, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(highestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.blue, yloc=yloc.price)

if (not na(lowestProfitPct))
    label.delete(labellow)
    labellow := label.new(bar_index, low, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(lowestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.orange, yloc=yloc.price)
    //label.new(bar_index, low, text="Profit\n" + str.tostring(lowestProfitPct,"#.##") + "%", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.orange, yloc=yloc.price)

